# Replacing stringvar from another stringvar, Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, replace

I'm trying to remove a string (%1, %~p1 = path of commandline parameter 1) from another string (%i, %%i = another path). I have tried the following:

```
SET relpath = !!%%i:%~p1=!!
```

But that returns:

```
relpath = \ISO til braending\filelist.bat:\ISO til braending\=
```

So nothing is removed; instead the value of %~p1 is added to relpath.

I'm trying to what is written at e.g. here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot use the sub-string replacement syntax on a `for` variable, so you need to assign its value to a normal environment variable first; by the way, when setting a variable, remove the spaces around the equal-to sign, as they are considered as part of the variable name and value otherwise...

Comment: Thanks aschipfl. I'm not sure I understand though. Do I need to set one variable to %%i and another to %~p1. Can you give me an example? About the equal-to sign the inserted code was modified for readability.

Comment: `%%i` is the variable of a `for` loop, so in the loop, do something like `set "relpath=%%i"`, then do `set "relpath=!relpath:%~p1=!"`; the surrounding `!` come from [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which has to be enabled first...